# Fetch Associated Data From Other Table

Tags: php, sql

Good day!

I have a transaction table and order table.

In transaction table i have a button which fetches the id send to another page then display order table that uses the id. My problem is it fetches only 1 row. How can i fetch all associated data from order table that uses Transaction ID

HERE IS MY CODE

```
<?php

$TransID = $_REQUEST["TransID];
$get_record = mysqli_query ($connection, "SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE TransNumber = '$TransID'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array ($get_record);

$order_id = $row["order_id"];
// so fort

?>
```

```
TransID--Details--Action
1--A--*Button*
2--B--*Button*
```

I want to display it like this when i press button

```
Order_ID---TransNumber---ProdName

1--1--BRAND X

2--1--BRAND Y

3--1--BRAND Z
```

Comment: Welcome. Don't post ALLCAPS, it's considered shouting/rude

Comment: Sorry sir. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through the array which you fetch from the database

```js
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($get_record)) {
  $order_id[] = $row["order_id"];
}

echo var_dump($order_id);
```

Comment: I'm getting a warning which say . Trying to access array offset...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mysqli fetch_assoc function instead of the mysqli_fetch_array function which will return an associative array.

To fetch all the rows you use the fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) function.

You should also consider using prepared statements for security reasons.

Comment: Here is the link to the docs for that function: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_assoc.asp

Comment: I already used mysqli_fetch_assoc instead of mysqli_fetch_array but i still fetch only 1 row instead of displaying all data.

Comment: If you want to fetch all the data at once then you need to use the fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) function. 
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_all.asp